# load content script after injecting html code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

how to load script after injecting html to a page?

the html code in injected on a click event.
the content scripts get loaded before the click event(on which html is injected)

the script contains listeners to the added nodes.
So when the button in injected node is clicked, the evnt in script fails to trigger as they were loaded before the html was injected.

what are the alternatives taht could be used?

and any way that i can load some of the scripts after injecting html?

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.facebook.com/*"],
      "css": ["css/chat_style.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-latest.min.js","js/socket.io.js","contentscript.js","js/chat_script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
```

contentscript.js injects the html to the facebook page on some click event on the page and the chat_script.js contains the click listener to the nodes injected by contentscript.js

the problem is chat_script gets loaded before the the html is injected.

Comment: Add relevant code to your question.

Comment: Can you add the HTML-injecting code to the question?

Answer (score -2):

You can inject the script programatically so it won't be loaded before the html is injected.

Here's an ex:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "chat_script.js"});
```

Add this to the contentscript.js after injecting the html.

More info in the chrome docs

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi

Comment: It's an incomplete answer: the important part is to detect when it's time to inject the code.

Comment: updated the answer. it shouldn't be hard because the html is injected programmatically.

Comment: Now the answer is _plain wrong_. First, content scripts cannot use `chrome.tabs` API. Second, this completely ignores the fact that HTML is injected asynchronously (or there wouldn't be a problem in the first place).

Comment: can i define the complete listeners in a function and call the function on the button click? will the scope of listeners be valid?